# yii get the result from table with checking two condition

Tags: php, mysql, sql, yii

i have two table

sub_user table

```
id user_id ref_id detail
 1    10      5     test
 2    11      0     rest
 3     5      5     best
 4    12      0     west
```

user table

```
user_id sub_user name
     5       0    A
     10      5    B
     11      5    C 
     12      0    D
```

i have yii query

```
$result = Yii::app()->db->createCommand() 
     ->select('s.*,u.name') 
     ->from('sub_user s')
     ->join('user u','s.user_id=u.user_id')
     ->where("sub_user=:uid",array(":uid"=>$id)) // here $id = 5
     ->queryAll();
```

with this query i got 
only two record from sub_user table 
with id **1,2**

i want to also 5 number user_id record with this query result // here 5 is $id
thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your query in where condition.

```
->where(" u.sub_user = :uid or s.user_id = :uid ",array(":uid" => $id))
```

Comment: no i think its only return one record which have user_id = 5.... but i want 10,11,5 user_id from sub_user table record and check user_id with user table

Comment: sorry my query is wrong i change it ->where("sub_user=:ui")